# ZF2 Tutorial error with TableGateway and AdapterInterface

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm currently getting the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway::__construct() must implement interface Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface, none given, called in /vagrant/zend/module/Album/Module.php on line 33 and defined in /vagrant/zend/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/TableGateway.php on line 31
```

I have been searching this for a while now and I'm only following the ZF2 tutorial. Any idea what can be wrong and how to solve it ?

Comment: Provide some code of Album Module.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola it is the same code as used here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours troubleshooting I have found out that the issue wasn't on the getServiceConfig method and it was one on the AlbumTable where I have forgot to add, on the construct, the TableGateway parameter.

The ZF2 error message doesn't help much and is misleading but once I have fixed the AlbumTable constructor (re-copied it) it worked.